# Switching Voltage Regulator not Outputting Correct Voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, surface-mount, layout

I am working with a LM2576T-ADJ that is taking as an input voltage a 2 cell Li-Po battery that in my application won't decrease below 8V and should output a voltage of approximately 6V to power a pair of Pololu Micrometal Gear Motors that will have a peak combined load of 3A.

I have followed the datasheet (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) and TI's Simple Switcher document (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva054c/snva054c.pdf?ts=1684356810650) to the best of my knowledge however when I assembled the circuit I got an output voltage of approximately 7.6V. My reading was taken with a multimeter as I don't have access to an oscilloscope and I am sure that the reading is somewhat correct as when I measure the voltage across the battery's leads I get 8V which corresponds to the voltage reading of a small Li-Po undervoltage module I have.

Below I have attached the manufacturer's schematic of the switching voltage regulator; the manufacturer's example layout for a PCB for the switching voltage regulator; my schematic for the switching voltage regulator circuit used in my project; and the layout of the components on my PCB.

[image][image][image][image]

In addition, the links to the components are:
[L1](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/_PROD-Tech-_C2983069.html)
[D1](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/_Shikues-_C475721.html)
U17

Also this is a 2 layer PCB so the bottom layer (blue) is the GND layer that is a copper pour. I have identified the fact that the pins on the LM2576T-ADJ TO-220-5 are very close together which makes soldering hard and there might be a short however I did a continuity test using my multimeter and there were only small resistances between pins 3 and 5 which are both connected to ground.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I want to get to the root cause of this issue as many projects I want to do in the future require high efficiency power supplies and I don't want to spend a lot of money on breakout boards with SMPS from the likes of Pololu.

Comment: The batteries won't go below 8 V? That's really low utilization for a 2-cell battery. Anyway, what's the voltage on the feedback pin look like? This looks like there's a failure of the feedback network, perhaps a resistor not soldered properly or something.

Comment: At the junction between R6 and R5 its 1.55V and at pin 4 it's 1.23V which is the Vref for the Feedback loop (does this have any correlation?). Also I don't want to go below 8V because I fear that the battery will lose too much charge - is this too conservative?

Comment: The fact that the voltage is that different is definitely a problem, you should measure the same voltage at both of those points. And li-ion batteries are usually used down to a charge of about 3.0 to 3.2 volts per cell (sometimes further below that even, but you start damaging the cell going too low); at 4.0 V per cell, the battery is still going to be around 95% charge.

Comment: These points being the the Feedback pin and the junction between the 2 resistors?

Comment: Those are the same circuit node, so they should have the same voltage. The fact that they don't indicates that something's not connected right somewhere.

Comment: I moved the components to a breadboard after soldering some wires on and I get a reading of 6.11V which means that there is a problem with the wiring on the PCB. I think the problem is related to the quality of the soldering I did on the LM2576; do you have any advice on soldering pins that are so close to each other (the TO-220-5 pins have a pitch of 0.05"), as it seems the solder joints are so close to each other that they might be touching?

Comment: Use less solder, and a fine point soldering iron (I often use a conical tip with a 0.2 mm tip radius). Very fine solder wire is also always helpful. Also, if you're just a hobbyist, don't bother with lead-free solder.

Comment: You can meassure the quality of your soldering with a multimeter and see if you have unexpected resistance between the pins.

Also If you soldered it incorrectly, the fault probably was between vcc and output pin, since the voltage drop on the output is about 400mV (looks like internal voltage drop in the LM2756). I would assume that the soldering fault had to be between GND and feedback pins, which would make the device think that the output voltage is too low and locking it into ON state. (that would explain the voltage drop)

Btw, I wouldn't put vias directly under component pads.

Comment: (In the layout there are what looks red whiskers between the nets to pin 1&2 near the pads of "U17" and D2.)